# mint_to from token.sol example from solang throw new Error(unknown signer: ${signature.publicKey.toString()});

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I tried to mint token with solang example contract:
https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang/blob/main/integration/solana/token.sol

and at `contract.functions.mint_to` it throw error `unknown signer: ${signature.publicKey.toString()`

Where is the error in code?

My js code reworked from
https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang/blob/main/integration/solana/token.spec.ts
here:

```
const web3     = require('@solana/web3.js');
const {  PublicKey, clusterApiUrl, Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, Keypair } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Contract, Program, publicKeyToHex }     = require('@solana/solidity');
const { readFileSync }                          = require('fs');
const { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, createMint, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, mintTo , splToken} = require('@solana/spl-token');

const SPL_TOKEN_ABI = JSON.parse(readFileSync('./Token.abi', 'utf8'));
const PROGRAM_SO = readFileSync('./bundle.so');


(async function () {
   console.log('Connecting to your local Solana node ...');
   const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');

    const payer            = Keypair.generate();
    const freezeAuthority  = Keypair.generate();
    const mintAuthority    = Keypair.generate();
    const program          = Keypair.generate();
    const storage          = Keypair.generate();
    console.log('address payer: ' + payer.publicKey.toBase58());

   console.log('Airdropping SOL to a new wallet payer.publicKey ...');
   const signature = await connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 1.5 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
   await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'confirmed');

   console.log('new Contract ...');

   const contract = new Contract(connection, program.publicKey, storage.publicKey, SPL_TOKEN_ABI, payer);
    
   console.log('address program.publicKey: ' + program.publicKey.toBase58());
   console.log('address storage.publicKey: ' + storage.publicKey.toBase58());

   await contract.load(program, PROGRAM_SO);

   await contract.deploy('Token', [], program, storage, 3096 *8);
   console.log('contract deployed ...');

    console.log('createMint ...');

    const mint = await createMint(
       connection,
       payer,
       mintAuthority.publicKey,
       freezeAuthority.publicKey,
       3
    );

    console.log('set_mint ...');
    await contract.functions.set_mint(publicKeyToHex(mint));

    console.log('getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount ...');
    const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            payer,
            mint,
            payer.publicKey
      )

    console.log('address mint: '                    + mint.toBase58());
    console.log('address tokenAccount.address: '    + tokenAccount.address.toBase58());
    console.log('address mintAuthority.publicKey: ' + mintAuthority.publicKey.toBase58());
    console.log('address payer.publicKey: '         + payer.publicKey.toBase58());

    console.log('mint_to ...');
        await contract.functions.mint_to(
            publicKeyToHex(tokenAccount.address),
            publicKeyToHex(mintAuthority.publicKey),
            100000,
            {
                accounts: [TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID],
                writableAccounts: [mint, tokenAccount.address],
                signers: [mintAuthority]
            },
        );
})();
```

Error logs after calling script:

```
/home/alex/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2690
        throw new Error(`unknown signer: ${signature.publicKey.toString()}`);
              ^

Error: unknown signer: CKq7xZwFqbaJtcFCChWuYFzgZMEoYRMZPftxAi7JTQi7
    at Transaction.compileMessage (/home/alex/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2690:15)
    at Transaction._compile (/home/alex/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2753:26)
    at Transaction.sign (/home/alex/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2858:26)
    at Connection.sendTransaction (/home/alex/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:7382:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/home/alex/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:3133:21)
```

How can I mint token with https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang/blob/main/integration/solana/token.sol smart contract?

Thank you for any help.

![Whole log is here: ] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGzM1.png)

Comment: unknown signer just means your passing a signer that is not the actual signer required to send the txn

Comment: If change signer to another account. for example payer. 
It throw error: TransactionError: An account required by the instruction is missing


 {
  accounts: [TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID],
  writableAccounts: [mint, tokenAccount.address],
  signers: [payer]
},

```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I impprted wrong program from anchor workspace. As the versions are broken as always, I had to reuse old `cargo.lock` that works and along with that copied everything else. In my tests I left:

`const stakingProgram = anchor.workspace.Oldprogram as Program<Program>;`

instead of

`const stakingProgram = anchor.workspace.Newprogram as Program<Staking>;`